# Why can't I use .?. in clojure?

Tags: clojure

I find a macro `.?.` on the website https://clojure.github.io/clojure-contrib/core-api.html. But I can't use it. I tried the example,

```
(.?. "foo" .toUpperCase (.substring 1))
```

the clojure repl returns an error:

```
user=> (.?. "foo" .toUpperCase (.substring 1))
Syntax error compiling at (REPL:1:1).
Unable to resolve symbol: .toUpperCase in this context
```

I notice the namespace of `.?.` is deprecated. Can't we use this macro anymore?

Answer (score 1):

It has been moved to [`core.incubator`](https://github.com/clojure/core.incubator), like [@phipsgabler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1346276/phipsgabler) said.

---

You should use [`some->`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/some-%3E) from clojure.core.

```clj
(some-> "foo" (.toUpperCase) (.substring 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

It has been moved to a separate module [`core.incubator`](https://github.com/clojure/core.incubator/).